# How to create a grid that resembles a list/stack UX?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-experience

Hello guys i am new to angular 2  and frontend in general and i would like to know what html component can i use for creating a visual list/stack whose elements can be  added or removed on click.All changes should update the visual list.

e.g Basically i want the user to "add" items of N kinds

```
1 2 3....N
```

For each press on 1/2/3/....N the list appends an item of the added kind.The user can see the state of the list and he can press on any element of the list and remove it.

For pressing 1->2->1->1 the list has to show visually something like:

```
1 2 1 1
```

If user presses on the second element (of type 2 in our case)  and then presses a delete button the list shrinks becoming.

```
1 1 1
```

The order of adding and deleting counts.The visual list has to get updated on each changed element.

The length of the List cannot get very large (7-10 items max) but i have to find a way to show all possible item options  which can get quite big.
Also [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O33IB.png)how should this be managed UI-wise?

**Sketch**:

[image]